# Toolbar Spacer not working in 3 panel design

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, toolbar

I have a 3 panel SwiftUI macOS app (running macOS Monterey Beta 9, Xcode 13 Beta 5), and I'm adding toolbar items to the window.

Some of these toolbar items have `Spacer`'s in between them, but I'm getting this weird behavior:
[image: Weird spacer behavior]
In the sidebar's toolbar area, there is a `Spacer` between the 2 buttons, but it doesn't seem to work. And in the detail panel, the `Spacer` is only semi-working.

Here is the sample code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("Sidebar")
            .frame(minWidth: 200)
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "sidebar.left") }
                Spacer() // Comment out this line, and detail panel works fine
                Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "play.fill") }
            }
        Text("Middle")
            .frame(minWidth: 200)
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "trash") }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
        Text("Detail")
            .frame(minWidth: 200)
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "scribble") }
                Spacer() // Comment out this line, and sidebar panel works fine
                Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle") }
            }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, removing the `Spacer` from the Sidebar seems to fix the problem on the detail panel. This also works in reverse, so removing the `Spacer` from the detail panel fixes the sidebar.

Here is the intended behavior (I edited the image):
[image]

What could the problem be here?

Comment: I can reproduce it, but don't have a solution. `toolbar` stuff on macOS in an odd beast. For example, if you try resizing your middle column, you'll see that the `toolbar` segment and the view below it don't actually retain the same width. It's all very odd to me...

Comment: @jnpdx 100%, I'm getting a lot of weird `toolbar` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sidebar").frame(minWidth: 200)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup (placement: .principal) {
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "sidebar.left") }
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "play.fill") }
                        }
                    }
                }
            Text("Middle").frame(minWidth: 200)
                .toolbar {
                   ToolbarItemGroup (placement: .principal) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Test").bold()
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "trash") }
                    }
                   }
                }
            Text("Detail").frame(minWidth: 200)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup (placement: .principal) {
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "scribble") }
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle") }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove the `.border(.red)` type code that doesn't work unless you have an extension installed, then running this code immediately crashes with the error "[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775806 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]" on macOS 11.3. This seems to be a result of setting all 3 `toolbar` groups to `.principal`. If I remove that, it runs.

Comment: I'll remove the borders, which were just for my tests. Works very well for me, with or without the borders. However I am on Monterey Beta 9, as in the question, using Xcode 13-beta, not release. Behaviour could be very different on older systems.

Comment: @workingdog Thanks for the answer! However I'm not looking to put all the toolbar items in the principal area. I updated the question to include the intended behavior.

Comment: The second picture you show is pretty much what my answer produces for me. 
Do you get something different on your system/target?

Comment: Correction: 
my mistake, I have been testing my code on macos Monterey with MacCatalyst.
This gives a very different looks than on macos only app. Sorry, I can delete my answer 
if you want.

Comment: @workingdog Don't worry about it. Thanks for your help though!